# Separate cookies for different origin subdomains

Tags: cookies, browser, cors, subdomain

Is it possible to not share a cookie between different origin subdomains? For example, I have an API hosted on AWS at e.g. `abcd1234.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. It is set up for CORS to allow access from `*.app.com`, and the auth cookie works fine. The problem is, I want to have different auth cookies for different `app.com` subdomains, so that you can be logged in as a different user for each subdomain. Currently, if I log in as an admin at `admin.app.com`, then access `user.app.com`, the browser is still sending the cookie set at `admin.app.com`.

Comment: If `admin.app.com` sets a cookie without any `Domain` attribute, the cookie in question will only be attached to subsequent requests to `admin.app.com`, not to `user.app.com`.

Comment: The cookie is set by the API (the .amazonaws.com one). It's being included in requests from the .app.com sites. Doesn't the Domain attribute only refer to the domain which is setting the cookie?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by: _Doesn't the `Domain` attribute only refer to the domain which is setting the cookie?_ However, you should look up how the `Domain` attribute works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#domaindomain-value

Comment: Yeah, it states "Defines the host to which the cookie will be sent.". Both app subdomains are sending the cookie to the same API domain. The issue is that I want each app subdomain to have a separate cookie, and not share the same cookie for the API.

Comment: The only way (omitting the `Domain` attribute and setting different cookies from different subdomains) to do that is explained in [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77609319/separate-cookies-for-different-origin-subdomains?noredirect=1#comment136824816_77609319). There's no other way.

Comment: This isn't about the cookie's domain though. The `Domain` attribute will affect whether or not `abcd1234.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` is set as the cookie's domain. I.e. which domain the cookie is sent `to`. It doesn't affect whether or not the cookie is sent `from` `user.app.com` and / or `admin.app.com`

Comment: Can you please clarify which Web origin currently sets the cookie?

Comment: The `Domain` attribute, when specified, extends the set of domains where the cookie will be sent to. The `SameSite` attribute, when `Lax` or `Strict` is specified as its value, restrict the domains from which the cookie will be sent.

Comment: `admin.app.com` makes a "login" call to `abcd1234.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`, which responds with `Set-Cookie` set the auth cookie.

Comment: Then what you're asking is not possible.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much. It seemed like CHIPS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Partitioned_cookies) would work, but that only works with eTLD+1. I ended up using different cookie names depending on the request's origin. If you want to add an answer that it's not possible, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Please feel free to write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible to do this. I instead opted for having separately named cookies based on the origin of the request.